# Detecting one account being accessed from multiple computers at the same time

Tags: 7, users

I need to detect member access to the same account from different computers or web browsers at the same time with same email and password?

Are there any options or modules to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to log the user out to prevent multiple logins at the same time, then you could use the [Session Limit](http://drupal.org/project/session_limit) module.

> Session Limit allows administrators to limit the number of
>   simultaneous sessions per user.

Also taken from the project page:

> Assuming the session limit is 1, if a user is logged in to a Drupal site from their work computer and they log in from their home computer, they would be forced to either log off the work computer session, or abort their new login from home.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any modules that do this, but you can see the user status login status. Have a look at how the admin menu module does this.

You can then build your own little module and deny or allow access to the site based on the status.

I can only speak for d6 as I haven't looked at d7/d8 as of yet.